# validating textbox's value according to regional and language settings

Tags: application-pages, validation, regional-settings

I have created an application page which contains many textboxes some of them must accept only decimals (amount). Administrators can change the language and regional settings and some counries has comma as decimal sign and others (english) has dot as decimal signs. How do I can make a proper valdiation for those textboxes based on regional or language settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For showing the language switch with localized content the one approach you can choose is content translation using Resource Files.

Reference Link : [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/07/using-resource-files-resx-when-developing-sharepoint-solutions.aspx)

2) The other approach you can go with using the below code block :

```
        int intLCID = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID;
        if (intLCID == 1025)
        {
            localText.Text = "فريدة عدد";
        }
        else 
        {
           localText.Text = "English";
        }
```

Note: intLCID=1025 denotes Arabic Language code and en-US denotes intLCID=1033 for else loop.

Comment: So I need to implement a custom validation of all textboxes that accepts decimal

Comment: there are two approaches for language switching MUI and Variant Site. So in MUI method yes you will need to set custom translations for everything and i have not checked with Variant Site method. May be you can get sharepoint things translated in Variant Site but other content we need to translate it.